# Drupal : Drupal6 views : Filter restriction

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I am a newbie to Drupal, hope somebody can answer my query.
I think I am facing a weird problem in views..I have a content type of say Company and have around 3-4 pages added to it. The sequence is as
1. Company - default page
2. View company
3. Search company
4. New page

The problem is when I go and add a Filter to the Search company page then that filter get shared with the default page and new page but doesn't get shared with the view company page, I am not sure what is causing this as I want that filter to be applicable for the search page and do not get shared across other pages.

is there a setting where I can restrict this filter getting shared ?

Thanks in advance
- Dev-Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a filter only for one display, you have to, on the configuration of that display :

- specify that the filters should "override" the default ones
- specific the specific filters you want on that display.

See [What are overrides?](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/overrides) for a little longer description.

Basically, on the configuration of the "Search company" display, when you are trying to configure filters, you should choose "override" before specifying your filters.

Comment: Thanks PM, I did the same stuff sometime back and it seems to be working fine.